# Why do images in flexboxes have different heights in different browsers?

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari

The following HTML renders very differently on Safari and Chrome:

```html
<a style="display:flex;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EaWkSxe.png" width=100>
</a>
```

In Chrome (Version 78.0.3904.70, on Mac), the image aspect ratio is preserved:

[image: An image demonstrating the aspect ratio is preserved]

In Safari (Version 11.1 (12605.1.33.1.3), on Mac), the image height is preserved:

[image: An image demonstrating the height is preserved]

It's fairly easy to make them render the same (just set the height),
but I do not understand why they are different in the first place.

Why do they render differently?

Comment: I'm unsure if there is a tag specifically for HTML rendering inconsistencies or standards. If you know a better tag for this or if the current tags are not appropriate, please let me know.

Comment: You can apply a `align-self: center;` style to the image for consistency between the 2 browsers without applying a height.    As for why the 2 are different i'm not sure.  Probably has something to do with how their rendering engines handle the flex container and image together.